# EasyAdmin How to update multiple Entities from one crud controller?

Tags: easyadmin

I have been trying to create a Product crud controller, but my application has many Product related entities, one in particular uses a non-standard manyToMany join table (not defined as ManyToMany but is an entity with multiple manyToOne relations, but with addional data stored alongside each row).

The same setup as described in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BjEGDosQfE

I can create the many to many relation using the association field, but i cant get it to load the individual entities because they dont "exist" as properties on the Product entity .

Also, with using an actual ManyToMany relation is it possible to edit them in the same crudcontroller? So that the users dont have to go to multiple crud pages? I want to be able to update a product record on a single page.